# Unique and Injective linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was asked to find the values of $a$ such that there is a atleast one injective linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ so that $L(v_i) = w_i$ where

$V = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 \\2 & 6 & 1 \\-2&-1&a^2-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $W = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 0 \\-a^2 & 6-2a & 3 \\-1 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

So if write it like this: $AV= W$
 and $A = V^{-1}W$ then i can apply row operations and find a value for $a$ so that $ker(A)$ is $0$ then i think i can find one linear injective mapping?

But

I was also asked to find a value for $a$ so that linear map **Injective** and **Unique** is. Does that mean that the input vectors should be linearly independent?

Comment: Is there **any** relation between the question in the first two lines of your post and those matrices $\;V,W\;$ ?? And what in the world is $\;A\;$ ?? And where do $\;v_i,\,w_i\;$ intervene in your question after their first appearance? As I see it, the question doesn't make any sense at all and I'm pretty surprised you've even gotten one answer which addresses...I don't know what!

Comment: @DonAntonio "What in the world is A"? Every linear transformation has a matrix such $L(V) = W $ is same as $A.V = W$  and $v_i$ is vector of matrix $V$ so i think there is nothing wrong to write $AV =W$ instead of writing for every vector $V_i , Av_i = w_i$.   There is for sure relation because $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ there i mean dimension of $V$ and $W$ is $3$.

Comment: @Kh Oh, I know all that, thank you. I meant "where in your question did you explain what relation $\;A\;$ has with $\;L\;$, which is what you wrote about ?! Nowhere it is explained, and there is also no reference at all to $\;v_i,w_i\;$ after your wrote them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique indeed means the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent, and injective, if the first condition is satisfied, means the vectors $w_i$ are.

Algebraically, this means:
$$\det V\ne 0\enspace\text{and}\enspace\det W\ne 0,\quad \text{or}\quad\det(VW)\ne 0.$$